# Замена точного вхождение в строке

Tags: функции, str-replace

Что не так в функции, никак не хочет произвести замену точного вхождения, восклицательные знаки заменяются, но вот запятые, двойные пробелы и точки не в какую не хотят заменятся.

```
$txt = 'Бойцы высокомобильной группировки !      привлекаются к решению  особых военных и политических задач везде , где есть интересы России . Большинство проведенных ими операций   -   государственная тайна . ';

function new_str ($as) {

    if (preg_match('/\D*\D/', $as) == true) {

         $as = str_replace(' ! ', '! ', $as);

    } elseif (preg_match('/ , /', $as) == true){

         $as = str_replace(' , ', ', ', $as);

    } elseif (preg_match('/ . /', $as) == true){

         $as = str_replace(' . ', '. ', $as);

    } elseif (preg_match('/\s\s/', $as) == true){

         $as = str_replace('  ', ' ', $as);

    } else {

       $as = $as;

    }

    return $as;
}


    echo new_str($txt);
```

Comment: Вы правы, не заметил синтаксис, и теги не проставлены.

Comment: Рекомендую разобраться как работает if...elseif...else. Когда срабатывает одно условие- остальные не проверяются и не выполняются.

Comment: @ReinRaus как можно с вами связаться?

Comment: [Как задать вопрос напрямую участнику Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/440/183314)

Answer (score 3):

В конструкции `if ... elseif ... else` выполняется блок кода из первого истинного условия. Все остальные условия будут пропущены.
В этом Ваша проблема.

Кроме того Вы выполняете лишнюю работу - проверку текста регулярными выражениями. Это совсем не нужно.
Просто сделайте "конвейер" замен:

```
$as = str_replace(' ! ', '! ', $as);
$as = str_replace(' , ', ', ', $as);
$as = str_replace(' . ', '. ', $as);
$as = str_replace('  ', ' ', $as);
```

Если вхождение не будет найдено, то и замена не будет совершена и строка пойдет дальше по "конвейеру" неизмененной.